# Can MS Visual Studio Enterprise develop office apps?

Tags: visual-studio

I bought MS Visual Studio Enterprise (cheaply & legally on eBay) because I wanted to develop an MS Outlook plugin.

[Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says

> Prerequisites You need the following components to complete this
>   walkthrough:
>
> An edition of Visual Studio that includes the Microsoft Office
>   developer tools. For more information, see 
>   [Configuring a Computer to> Develop Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

which says

> Software  Supported versions
>   - Visual Studio Professional
>   - Visual Studio Premium
>   - Visual Studio Ultimate Important: You must select the Microsoft Office 
>     Developer Tools check box during setup.

That's it?!  Can't I develop an Office add-in with MS VS Enterprise?

When I `File/new/project/c# (or VB)`, I don't see an option for Office Add-in

I suppose that it is possible that I installed and did not check an option. Before I uninstall & reinstall, can anyone who uses the Enterprise version conform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can't I develop an Office add-in with MS VS Enterprise?

`Visual Studio Enterprise` has all features that included in `Visual Studio Professional`.  Due to the size of the tables located on the following two sources, it would be next to impossible for me to quote them, but it also wouldn't be relevant for `Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate` anyways.  The supplied my research sources regardless.

- [Compare Visual Studio 2017 IDEs](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/)
- [Visual Studio Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/)

> In addition to the features provided by the Professional edition, the
>   Enterprise edition provides a new set of software development,
>   database development, collaboration, metrics, architecture, testing
>   and reporting tools.

[Microsoft Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Ultimate_2010)

> When I File/new/project/c# (or VB), I don't see an option for Office
>   Add-in

In order to be provided that project template option you must install the `Microsoft Office Developer Tools`.  In previous versions, it was an optional feature that must be chosen to be installed.  In the current version of Visual Studio, you download it from Microsoft, as an [extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/).  You must also have a support version of Office installed obviously.

It is worth pointing out that `Visual Studio Ultimate` does not currently exist, and the documentation you linked to, does not apply to Visual Studio 2015+

Comment: D'oh!  Re-running the install, with "modify" option showed me that I had not, in fact, checked "MS Office add-ins" when first installing.  I a sure that your clear explanation will be  a help to others. Thanks